# Number.toLocaleString(), minimumFractionDigits acts like maximum

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
10.00000001.toLocaleString('en-GB', {useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 2})
```

I expect it to return `'10.00000001'` but what I get is `10.00`.
When I change the minimum the accurracy changes accordingly.

The minimum acts like its a maximum.

Setting `maximumFractionDigits`does not change anything. It is ignored completely.

I tested this with node 8.1.4 and in FF Quantum.

Any ideas why `toLocaleString` acts so strange?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation https://www.jsman.net/manual/Standard-Global-Objects/Number/toLocaleString, minimum is the number of digits you want in decimal.
Below two examples will give clear understanding

```js
var n = 10.00000001;
var x;
// It will give 8 decimal point because min is 0 (i.e. Atleast it should have one decimal point) and max it can have till 8 
x = n.toLocaleString('en-GB', {useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: n.toString().split('.')[1].length});
console.log(x);
// If you put value 2.301 it gives 2.3 since it omits 0 in 2.30 (i.e. 
n = 2.311;
// It will give 1 decimal point because min to max is 1
x = n.toLocaleString('en-GB', {useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
console.log(x);
// It will give 1 decimal point eventhough we didn't have decimal points
n = 2;
x = n.toLocaleString('en-GB', {useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 1});
console.log(x);
```